# SQL: Retrieving up to the parent rows for any of the child row in a same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, recursion, parent-child

I don't know whether this is duplicate or not but I could not get help in proper direction for the same hence asking here.

I have following table schema,

Menu {ID, ParentID, Name}

What I want to do is I want a stored procedure in which when I pass ID as a parameter, I want all the parent rows of this ID until the ParentID is 0.

For example, this is my data:

{1, 0, Home}

{2, 1, System}

{3, 1, Data}

{4, 2, Settings}

{5, 2, Access}

So, when I pass 5 as a parameter to store procedure, I want it to return Access, System and Home. Note here that ParentID is not tightly coupled with ID hence it can contain 0, where 0 means the parent node of all the children.

Its kind of child-parent retrieving stuff and I can do that using while loop but I want it in a single query.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: This is a root/leaf node question, and there are many related/duplicate questions on this site.  What have you tried so far?  Most solutions tend to use a recursive CTE - after following any examples, what in your query isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a recursive common table expression to get what you want;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, 1 AS level FROM menu WHERE id=5
  UNION ALL
  SELECT menu.*, cte.level + 1 AS level FROM menu
  JOIN cte ON menu.id = cte.parentid
)
SELECT * FROM cte
ORDER BY level DESC;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bc584/4).

The base case here is the entry with id=5.
The recursive part simply picks the parent of the last row and returns that.
A `level` field is added to show which level we're currently at. It's then used to order things in the desired order.

Comment: Awesome! works like a charm!

Comment: One more help, is there any way to order it from Parent to child? for example here I want in this order Home > System > Access.

Comment: @PratikGaloria Updated the answer with a level counter that can be ordered by.